# mouseover event remain open even after open it in new window in javaScript with Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

May be my question title is unclear but here is detail explanation. I created calender with fusion of Ajax, JavaScript in Classic Event. in such a way, so that if user mouse over on any date of calender then ajax call and a small pop-up open as it show day time table of that date. now when i click it on that date it will open in new window, and that is okay that i wrote.

But the problem is when i open it in new window that date schedule, even after it for few second that pop-up of ajax will remain(like mouseover event remain in execution). and i don't want it. If i open that date schedule in new window than it must be stop the execution of that mouseover event.

Suggestion are welcome, i don't know it may be my code problem or it may be browser problem or it may be event problem. And yes, my whole web application is written in classic asp.

Comment: add some screenshot or code otherwise you wont get solution

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your code I'm not exactly sure your problem, but a couple of things to check are if you're using .onmouseenter or .onmouseover, these will only fire once when the mouse enters, and won't fire again when the mouse leaves, so you will have to write some more code to tell the ajax window to go away .onmouseleave

Also this probably isn't the problem, but maybe try .blur on the element when the pop-up opens.

Comment: I know that it's in my mind when i post question that its good if i also include 'code' but the problem is code is so long as well as it has lot dependency on other files.

Comment: You don't need to (/ shouldn't) post the whole code... just the relevant snippits (in this case the JS which controls the pop-ups). You will get a lot better / more answers then.